# How do I cache the top level navigation tree in my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, optimization

I have this logic in my haml file

```
    %ul.menu
      - Page::NAVS.each do |navigation|
        %li.main_nav.has-sub
          = link_to navigation, main_headers(navigation)
          %ul
            - Page.parent_nav(navigation).each do |page|
              = page_children(page)
```

which builds the navigation for my navigation menu and I want to know I can cache this per user. The navigation doesnt change on a peruser basis so the first time the user visits the page the navigation stays the same. Is there a way to cache this on the first visit and change only when i need to

I was looking at `fresh_when` but i wasnt sure the best way to implement that or page caching here...any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that [fragment caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching) might be a good option